# Is it Incorrect to use Copy Paste for Backup

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, backup, external-hard-drive

I have a 'large' (~200 GB) music collection on my storage drive in my PC. For backup and mobile DJ purposes I keep a copy of this folder on an external USB hard drive.
Any new music that I obtain goes to the storage drive on my PC. Every month or two I want to add those new files to the external drive. There can be up to a few gigabytes of new files that I need to copy over.
For this application, where I do not care about changes made to already existing files, is it correct to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>? When Windows prompts me if I want to overwrite existing files I just hit "no".

This method works for me so it is "correct", but I am wondering if there is a better (safer, faster, etc) way. Please note that my external drive is plugged into my PC usually just for this transfer, so a scheduled sync isn't an option (but nothing wrong with manually starting a sync).

Comment: Personally I like to use a script that I created for Xcopy...does the same thing but takes the manual labor out of it...

Comment: @TheX Well I do hit "No to all" rather than "No" for each one ;)

Comment: Well there are multiple ways to skin a cat... Can I say that here?

Comment: @valsidalv What @TheX meant is that he would run an `Xcopy` script that is already set up to copy everything. Just click it and you're golden, removing the manual labor of copying, pasting and setting what isn't overwritten every time.

Comment: simple batch file on the external hdd involving `robocopy` with switches to suppress prompts will do the trick. Once set, you just double click the batch file to "sync". Can have a log file generated too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155) should suffice your needs.

It allows you to declare folder pairs from your PC to the external drive and run the sync manually.